# Chrome Debugging: put a JS breakpoint on a node content value change

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I can put a DOM changed breakpoint on everything except node content changed. Which is exactly what I would need.. any suggestion?

An example page to try: https://www.etoro.com/discover/markets/cryptocurrencies

EDIT: I tried to follow the advice of @wOxxOm to put breakpoints in the containing element but it still doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why `java` tag? `Java` and `Javascript` are totally different languages... I added the correct tag

Comment: @Aristotle my mistake, thanks for the correction

Comment: Since text content is actually a text node, `subtree modifications` will be triggered.

Comment: @wOxxOm but I've tried and it doesn't happen. I will add a screen to the question.

Comment: It happens when the parent element and its entire tree is replaced so you need to observe a higher ancestor.

Comment: @wOxxOm: still not working.. (I put a picture showing my attempt). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Ancestor" doesn't limit you to one level so keep going higher.